# Value of argument in #define C?

Tags: c-preprocessor

I'm wondering if there is any possibility of replacing arguments in directive `#define` by the values of the arguments, they actually have in program. Here's the code:

```
typedef struct {
uint8_t b0 : 1;
uint8_t b1 : 1;
uint8_t b2 : 1;
uint8_t b3 : 1;
uint8_t b4 : 1;
uint8_t b5 : 1;
uint8_t b6 : 1;
uint8_t b7 : 1;
} BIT_FIELD;
#define _PORTD (*( volatile BIT_FIELD*)&PORTD)
#define kupa(s) _PORTD.b##s
void SentByteTo74HC595 (uint8_t val){
    for(int i = 7 ; i >=0 ; i--) {
        DS = kupa(i);
        SHCPpulse() ;
    }
```

The problem is that kupa makes _PORTD.bi insted of _PORTD.b0, PORTD.b1 etc. I was trying diffrent ways with # or ## but I'm not sure if it's even possbile to achieve what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Because preprocessor (the thing that expands macros) is run even before the compiler. What you want is to access names of struct's fields in runtime, which is impossible, because names of fields are not preserved. C is not a dynamic language and do not have reflections.

You can, however, write your for iteration as a separate define and call it 8 times. Not the best solution, though - in your case I'd use bit shifts instead of bit fields. It's easier to support, use and read.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-processor directives are processed and applied prior to processing (i.e. compilation). `kupa` is a pre-processor macro, so the compiler never sees it. So no, you can't do it like this.

What you're trying to do is not portable, how the bits are stored is compiler dependent.

You may be better using bit manipulation such as defining enums which specify a given bit

```
enum {
    b0 = 0x001,
    b1 = 0x002,
    b3 = 0x004,
...
};
```

You may still need to perform (e.g.) endian conversions on values depending on how you are exchanging them.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
uint8_t b0 : 1;
uint8_t b1 : 1;
uint8_t b2 : 1;
uint8_t b3 : 1;
uint8_t b4 : 1;
uint8_t b5 : 1;
uint8_t b6 : 1;
uint8_t b7 : 1;
} BIT_FIELD;

union u_ToSend {
uint8_t ui8val;
BIT_FIELD BFval;
} ;


    void SentByteTo74HC595 (uint8_t val){
union u_ToSend tmp;
tmp.ui8val = val;
for (int i = 7; i >=0; i--){
    DS = tmp.BFval.b7 ;
    tmp.ui8val <<= 1 ;
    SHCPpulse() ;
}
```

Is there any other way to write it, so that program consume less RAM and Flash memory ?